# make change after vector::at returns a reference

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  vector<int> nums {0,1,2};
  vector<int> copy {0};
  copy.at(0) = nums.at(0);  // nums.at(0) returns a reference
  nums.at(0) = -1;          // why this line doesn't change copy[0]

  std::cout << copy.at(0);  // print 0
}
```

Hi, as code indicates, it looks like changing of nums.at(0) doesn't affect copy.at(0).
Does `copy.at(0) = nums.at(0);` call the copy-assignment operator a copy? 
It doesn't make sense to me this line actually do a copy, because `copy.at(0)` also returns a reference.

Comment: You obviously misunderstood something. `copy.at(0) = nums.at(0);` doesn't tie those references together.

Comment: `int& = int&` will copy, you can't reassign references, you only assign to the object they refer to

Comment: You say they are a copy. That makes sense. I want to understand more in-depth. Is it because compiler calls the copy-assignment operator of int? and the corresponding signature is the reference one ```class_name & class_name :: operator= ( const class_name & ) (2) ```

Comment: @echoLee "*is it because compiler calls the copy-assignment operator of int?*" - essentially, yes. Though `int` is not a class type, there is no `int::operator=`, the assignment is built into the language itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are bound on initialization. After that the reference refers to the bound object and cannot be made to refer to something else.

Maybe this is best understood by means of an example:

```
int x = 6;
int& x_ref = x;  // bind x_ref to x

int y = 12;
x_ref = y;       // assign the value of y to x
```

In your code `copy.at(0)` does return a reference, however you cannot rebind that reference to something else. Instead `copy.at(0) = something;` will assign `something` to what `copy.at(0)` references.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree to above the comments, you have misunderstood.
Also references must be initialized at the time of declaration,
This can possible illustrate your case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  vector<int> nums {0,1,2};
  int& copy = nums.at(0); 
  nums.at(0) = -1; 

  std::cout <<"copy is"<< copy;  // print -1
}
```

**Be warned:** this is asking for trouble, as soon as the vector reallocates or element is deleted, the reference will be dangling.
See also [The concept of references in C++](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/cpp-reference-variable/)

Online [demo](https://ideone.com/BaxFZn)

Comment: Why in this case copy is changed? ```int& copy = nums.at(0); ``` operands of '=' are reference, which is the same as mine.   I think I am kinda confused about when compiler makes a copy. Because in my case ```copy.at(0) = nums.at(0);``` is making a copy. In your case, ```int& copy = nums.at(0); ``` is not a copy.